# Meaning of OrderBy(x => 1) in C# LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I encountered a linq expression that goes something like this:

```
var result = someCollection.Where(some_filter_condition).OrderBy(x => 1).ToList();
```

I'm wondering what's the purpose of the lambda expression **x => 1** in the OrderBy linq method?

Comment: Is this the exact code? Can you paste piece of exact code and where the result is being used?

Answer (score 5):

It seems pretty meaningless to me. It's going to "sort" the sequence, but instead of basing the sort order on a property of each element, it's going to use the key `1` for every element. This would be the same as not sorting at all.

I would guess that this was a placeholder that someone meant to go back and implement, but never did.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that some method would require input of type IOrderedQuery, so in order to convert it to required type, user might have added this lambda.

Comment: that'd be a good explanation if it weren't for the `.ToList()` at the end